# Reference request: The geometry of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and related questions

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Can anyone please recommend some good reading on the geometry of linear groups and their actions?

An example of the kind of question I am interested in: Explicitly describe a fundamental domain for the action of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, and compute the volume of the quotient.

I'm familiar with this particular question and its answer, but it is evidently a special case of a more general theory and I would love to see it treated in context. I looked briefly at Borel's Linear Algebraic Groups, Lang's $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, a couple intro books on Lie groups -- and at a brief glance, none of them seemed to squarely address this kind of question.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest Siegel's "Lectures on the geometry of numbers", lectures XIV and XV


Comment: Borel's softcover book *Introduction aux groupes arithmetiques* (Hermann, 1969) is helpful for fundamental domains (though it still has notational inconsistencies after he spliced two older sets of lecture notes). For some special cases I tried to write this down in Borel's style but in English in my Springer Lecture Notes 789 *Arithmetic Groups*. In general, the volume of a fundamental domain will be infinite.

Comment: About infinite volume (as raised by @Jim H.): this is a genuine issue for "Fuchsian" subgroups of SL(2,R), and more generally for real-rank-one groups to which (Mostow-Margulis-Zimmer) rigidity does _not_ apply. One could already declare that one's only interest was in _arithmetic_ subgroups (congruence-or-not), in which case volumes are always finite. Nevertheless, indeed, there is a substantial school of investigation concerning non-finite-co-volume discrete subgroups of SL(2,R), SL(2,C), and SO(n,1)'s more generally. (I don't know/understand the sensibilities/goals of that.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Siegel's "Geometry of Numbers", Godement's Seminaire Bourbaki from 1967-8 does "reduction theory" including a very nice adelic version of Minkowski-Siegel-Borel.

If the goal is obtaining a Siegel-set approximation to a fundamental domain, rather than a precise fundamental domain, the GL(n,Q) case (and the anisotropic orthogonal group case...) is recapped in http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/reduction.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can try to take a look in Dave Witte's book about arithmetic groups here - http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/IntroArithGroups.html
He also presents in his site a dynamical approach to this subject (due to Margulis) which proves that sets like G(Z) are lattices in fairly general settings, without the full reduction theory - http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/talks/arith-grps-are-latts-chgo-6-10.pdf.

The volume computations is easy when you have explicit fundemental domain, but as Paul mentioned, you can usually get only a Siegel domain.
The general theory here is due to Langlands via the theory of Eisenstein series. You can look here - http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/chev-ps.pdf.
If you want to see just more explicit formula (say for PSL2), it appears as a guided exercise in Bump's book.

Another approach is to use the Siegel-Weil theorem, as Alex Eskin indicates here - [Volume of fundamental domain and Haar measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70081/volume-of-fundamental-domain-and-haar-measure)