# kostant partition function vs Haar measure

Tags: rt.representation-theory, cv.complex-variables

I am trying to understand the relationship between the Kostant partition function and the Haar measure.  Both seem to involve the Vandermonde determinant:

$$ \Delta(\theta) = \prod_{i< j} |e^{i\theta_i} - e^{i\theta_j}|$$

According to question: [Explicit computations using the Haar measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36025/explicit-computations-using-the-haar-measure) integrating over the Unitary group seems to involve integrals with Vandermonde determinant in the numerator,

$$ \langle f \rangle_1 = \int_{[0,2\pi]^n} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n \;\Delta  (\theta)^2 f(\theta)$$

while Kostant partition function seems to involve Vandermonde determinant in the demominator:

$$ \langle f \rangle_1 = \int_{[0,2\pi]^n} d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n \;\Delta  (\theta)^{-2} f(\theta)$$

Is there a name for this second measure?  These [notes](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~brweber/Courses/2013/Math651/Notes/L16_WeylDimI.pdf) suggest the Weyl denominator and Kostant partition function are reciprocal.

Comment: Are you sure? Does not look integrable to me.... Unless you only integrate functions that vanish quadraticaly in $\theta_i-\theta_j$.

Comment: @oferzeitouni Here is an example by Doron Zeilberger, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9811108.  It *looks like* Selberg integral, but perhaps not quite?  I am trying to find clarification.

Comment: The function $|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}|^{-2}$ is not integrable. If you do not mean an integral but rather a formal power series expansion, that's a different story.

Comment: I would say "the Kostant partition function is the _Fourier transform of_ the reciprocal of the Weyl denominator", in that the first is a function on the weight lattice of a torus and the second is a function on the torus itself.